# include and using declaration

Tags: c++, include, using-directives, using-declaration

```
using ::bb::cascades::Application;

#include <bb/cascades/Application>
```

What do these two declaration mean?

And are there any good tutorials which states the using directive/declaration deeply?Thanks.

Comment: You should probably grab and read a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#include` is a prepocessor directive. It basically tells the prepocessor to take the given file and replace the `#include` line with the files content.

`using` on the other hand makes it possible to use names inside a `namespace` (structs, enums, functions) without the `namespace` prefix. In this case `::bb::cascades::Application` will enable you to use write

```
Application app;
```

instead of

```
::bb::cascades::Application app;
```

if `::bb::cascades::Application` is a default-constructible class.

### *"Why do I ever need to use `#include`?"*

In order to use a function or to create an object the compiler must know the structure of this things, for example the functions signature or the member and methods of a class. These things are written in header files. Lets have a look at a very simple example, where we provide some module (called `module`):

#### The module `module`

```
// MODULE_HPP
// only declarations, no code
namespace module{
    struct dummyStruct{
        void dummyMethod(char);
        char dummyMember;
    };
    double dummyFunc(double);
};
```

```
// MODULE_CPP
// actual implementation
namespace module{
    void dummyStruct::dummyMethod(char c){
        dummyMember = c;
    };
    void dummyFunc(double a){
        return a + 1;
    }
};
```

As you can see our `module` consists of a struct with a member and a method, and a simple function. Note that we wrap everything up in the namespace `module`. Now we have another program which wants to use `module`:

```
#include <iostream>
using module::dummyFunc;

int main(){
    std::cout << dummyFunc(1) << std::endl;
}
```

And this won't work, because the compiler doesn't know about both the namespace `module`. You need to add the declaration, which can be done by using `#include` (see first paragraph of this answer):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "module.hpp"
using module::dummyFunc;

int main(){
    std::cout << dummyFunc(1) << std::endl;
}
```

<sup>Note that you'll need to compile both module.cpp and main.cpp, otherwise you'll get linker errors.</sup>

Comment: Then why do I ever need to use include? I can do what the 'include' can do with 'using directive' right?

Comment: no you cannot. you can't bring into scope something that you haven't included with #include . "using" only allows you to use things from other scope without fully qualifying them. But the scope has to be visible by itself which is what you use #include for

Comment: Can you please explain with an example :) Thanks.

Comment: @kalkin: Improved my answer.

Comment: So to make the example work I need to 'include' the file where the namespace 'module' is declared right?